# Hash # is not passing as route parameter in Slim Framework API

Tags: php, routes, frameworks, slim

I am trying to pass 'Hello world # world' as route parameter, but getting only 'Hello world' as args value as output. Rest of data getting truncated.

```
$this->post(’/postText/{data}’, function ($request, $response, $args) {

    if($request->isPost()) {
        echo $feed = $args[‘data’]; //My input is ’ Hello world #world’. Output is only ‘Hello world’
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass anything that can be urlencoded as route parameters. It should be passend inside request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` is a special character in the url spec, you can't use it as input unless encoded.

From php use: `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`

From js use something like: `encodeURIComponent()`

That way you'll get `%23` instead of `#`, which will get stripped.